# Porque solo se actualiza un solo chart de tres con react-chartjs-2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

Resulta que tengo un modal, el cual contiene un campo de texto que registra valores numéricos. Luego el valor que se registro se pasa por un ciclo para que llene un arreglo con la cantidad que se registro en el campo de texto. Después de esto los valores son enviados a 3 gráficos para que se actualicen sus datos.

El problema que ocurre, es que solo se actualiza el ultimo gráfico. No se que esta pasando por que al parecer los demás gráficos si reciben los valores, pero no los actualiza.

Por favor alguien que pueda ayudarme. Acá dejo el código en StackBlitz.

[Código en StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/updatechartjs)

Answer (score 0):

Ya supe cual era el error resulta que tengo una variable fuera de la función chart.js
solo es colocarla dentro y se soluciona.

antes era así:

```
var chartReference = {};
export default function charts(props) {
  useEffect (() => {
  ...
```

y debía ser así:

```
export default function charts(props) {
 var chartReference = {};
 useEffect (() => {
 ...
```